# SIGINT while doing std::thread::join()

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a `main()`, which spawns a thread, and then joins to it.
I want to be able to CTRL-C the program, so I would install SIGINT handler in `main` (the spawn thread will ignore this signal). When I am in sig-handler I will cancel the spawned thread with `cancel()`, but what happens with the current 'join()', which was active during the signal invocation. 
My guess is that I will get EAGAIN or EINTR, and I would have to make `join()` in loop. Am I right? Thank you.

The question is: Is this legal with mulithreading. I don't mind to just set a flag withing SIGINT handle, but what happens with the `join()` call?

Comment: You guess? Or you saw this behavior and try to understand it? Can you add a twenty-line program to reproduce what you've seen?

Comment: Why don't you just test it and find out? This just sounds like "Do my work for me and tell me what happens."

Comment: It is actually my guess. I am using C++11 thread facilities, this is just simplified version of what my indentions are.

Comment: I doubt that it is legal to call `cancel()` in a signal handler. There are very few functions that are allowed to be called within one. And since on a lot of OSs a signal can be delivered to any thread (including the one you want to cancel), I doubt any thread management functionality may be called from within a thread handler.

Comment: @Tudor: Maybe what he really wanted to ask was "what behaviour is guaranteed"

Comment: Well, I will do that, it is just with mulithreading things are not that obvious. Yes it might work, but there may be something very wrong with it anyways. I don't want you to do my work. If somebody has experience with this situation may clarify things.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, Thanks. Is there any way to stop gracefully program threads with CTRL-C?

Comment: @DragomirIvanov: This would depend on your OS and the facilities it provides. On many POSIXish systems it is common practice to have one dedicated thread that gets all signals by using per thread signal masks. On many OSs however it is not a problem to exit the main thread while other threads are still running

Comment: @PlasmaHH Yes, I will use Linux only. can it be `main()` thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Signals and threads? Here be dragons! You have to [fully-specify the masks](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/sigprocmask.html), or else [any thread may receive the signal](http://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/all-about-linux-signals?page=11).

The signal handler should generally not assume it is running in the "main" thread. Rather, it should post a message and return, [analagously to thread interruption](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.interrupt). The main thread can pick this up later in an event loop or whatever and then join.

Comment: Thank you for the links. That's all I needed.

Answer (score 1):

`std::thread::join()` has a `void` return type, so cannot return `EINTR`. On POSIX platforms it is likely a wrapper around `pthread_join`, which [does not return `EINTR`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_join.html). Joining a thread should not return **or throw** until the thread has been successfully joined-with, provided it is called on a joinable thread.

As an aside, it may not be safe to cancel the thread from a signal handler. `std::thread` does not have a `cancel()` member function, so I presume you have written your own. You therefore need to check that it is safe for use in a signal handler --- `pthread_cancel()` is not listed as a function that is safe to call from a [signal handler](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html#tag_02_04_03), for example.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, `join()` is `void`, but it can throw `std::system_error` which can embed `EINTR`, this is not an issue.
Yes, std::thread doesn't have `cancel()`, I will use mine implementation of it. Basically I want to flag the thread to cancel itself.

Comment: `join()` shouldn't throw anything unless the thread is not joinable (e.g. because you sneakily already used `pthread_join()` on the `native_handle()`).

Comment: I have read `pthread_join()` man page, it states explicitly that it will not return EINTR. I will just try to implement this logic, and will report back here.